# How change to next route

Tags: php, laravel

Two routes

```
Route::get('{page}', ['uses' => 'PageController@show']);
Route::get('{city}', ['uses' => 'CityController@show']);
```

Route model bindings

```
$router->bind('page', function($key, $binder) {
    return Page::firstByUrl($key);
});
$router->bind('city', function($key, $binder) {
    return City::firstByUrl($key);
});
```

How call (enter in the) CityController (and call city bind) if Page model does not find?
always call only PageController, may be "middleware" helps me or another way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't, at least not with your current route definitions. That's because `{page}` and `{city}` mean the same thing as far as the router is concerned. It's the same as if they were `{param}` and `{param}`, which means that those two route definitions are equal as far as matching goes and it will always match the first one defined, which in your case will always call `PageController@show`.

The name you give them in the route definition is only to help **you** identify the parameter. So for example if you were to access the following two URLs:

```
http://example.com/about
http://example.com/london
```

The router can't possibly know which of those is a page name and which is a city, because to the router `about` and `london` are variable values, nothing more.

---

Instead you should find a way to differentiate the two, something like:

```
Route::get('pages/{page}', ['uses' => 'PageController@show']);
Route::get('cities/{city}', ['uses' => 'CityController@show']);
```

Now the router will know that after `pages` comes a page name and after `cities` comes a city name and the following will work just fine:

```
http://example.com/pages/about
http://example.com/cities/london
```

You can read more about the subject in the [Laravel Routing Documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#route-parameters).